# Question concerning group action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

On an exercise sheet I try to do we have the following group action $$\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n\\
(\overline{1},x) \to -x$$ I do not quite understand, since $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has two elements and how the group action is defined since $\mathbb{Z}_2$ consists of equivalence classes. May someone help me?

Comment: Actually, your action is by $\mathbb{Z}_n$ in the second line.

Comment: You first wrote $\;\Bbb Z_n\;$ ...is $\;n=2\;$ ?

Comment: I am terribly sorry it is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Already corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\;\Bbb Z_2=\{0,1\}\;$ , so if you want **a group action**, then

$$a\in\Bbb Z_2\,,\,\,x\in\Bbb S^n\implies a\cdot x=\begin{cases}x,&a=0\\{}\\-x,&a=1\end{cases}$$

Now check this indeed defines an action on that sphere...and don't worry about what the elements of $\;\Bbb Z_2\;$ *are*: there are only two of them: the neutral element $\;0\;$ and $\;1\;$ , with the rule $\;1+1=0\;$ and etc.

Comment: Thanks. I will check this. I think that I was confused by above notation. First thought that it is $(\mathbb{Z}_2,\cdot)$ instead of $(\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$.

Comment: $\;\left(\Bbb Z_2,\,\cdot\right)\;$ is not even a group, so it *must* be with $\;+\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

The class $[0]$ acts on $x$ by sending it to $x$. The class $[1]$ acts on $x$ by sending it to $-x$ (which is still on the $n$-sphere). This is indeed a group action.